# Timestamp validation Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I use Firestore v9 in React project. I'm trying to add an item with a creation date. I want to make sure that the date is up to date and the user has not changed it.

My add function:

```
import { collection, addDoc, Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

    const startSignal = async () => {
            try {
                const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "signals"), {
                    active: true,
                    createdAt: Timestamp.now()
                });
                console.log(docRef);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
```

My firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /signals/{document=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.createdAt == request.time;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to add, I get a refusal. I think that at the time of execution and processing of the request, the time does not match.

How can I make sure that the request has the correct time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only value that always equals `request.time` in security rules is the token returned by `serverTimestamp()`.  `serverTimestamp()` is discussed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp).

```
import { serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "signals"), {
    active: true,
    createdAt: serverTimestamp()
});
```

Comment: How to access serverTimestamp with require notation?